# Entity Framework linq to stored procedures

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameterized-query

I using plain LINQ to query my database in my MVC web application. I have queries similar to this one

```
list = context.Courses.Join(
            context.Departments,
            course => course.DepartmentId,
            department => department.ID,
            (course, department) => new { course, department })
        .Select(f => new FriendlyCourseViewModel
        {
            ID = f.course.ID,
            Acronym = f.department.Acronym,
            CourseNumber = f.course.CourseNumber,
            CourseName = f.course.CourseName
        });
```

where context is my dbcontext class. I'd like certain LINQ queries to use sanitized input. Should I be making all of my LINQ queries into SP (stored procedures) to sanitize my input? If yes, is there an easy way I can convert my LINQ to a SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about using paramerterized queries? If so, Entity Framework is already doing that.

Comment: Yes, when I pass in a value into a WHERE clause with LINQ, I want to be sure that it isn't vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Take a look at the sql sent to the sql server. You will see that it is parameterized.

Comment: Where might I view the Sql Profiler? In a menu?

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Comment: I am using a database connection in Microsoft visual studio. I don't know if that's something you'd be able to tell me if I have a profiler or not